# What API do apps like Battery Doctor use to free up RAM

Tags: ios, xcode

How do apps like battery doctor able to free RAM on my iphone. what API do they use? Any example/reference please?

Initially i thought these apps just fake it. Now i used two apps. Used one to clean up the memory and then open the other app to find the memory was really cleaned by the previous one. So there should be some level of access apple should have provided.

**update1:**

Why am asking this? Try this yourself. 
Install Battery doctor(https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/battery-doctor-master-battery/id446751279?mt=8) and Wdgts app(https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wdgts-collection-awesome-notification/id916103272?mt=8). Now Add Memory & Disk widget to Todays widget and check the memory available. Go to Battery doctor and clean memory. Open the todays notification and you will see the memory displayed has changed and cleaned.

Comment: Note: Wdgts is iOS 8 only.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess but they probably cause the OS to invoke a low memory handler which in turn causes it to send messages to some apps to free memory and to shutdown others.  The easiest way for them to do that would be to just allocate a lot of memory. Depending on the maturity of the OS, they may have to actually write to each memory block to ensure it is backed. Then free it. Immediately.

Answer (score 0):

They just fake it. iOS apps are sandboxed and have no access to memory outside of what the operating system has allocated to the app. Only the operating system can terminate processes to free up memory.

Comment: I'm guessing they consume memory until they get a low memory warning, then stop. This will cause background processes to quit.

Comment: But then how 2 different apps from totally two different developers showing the same changes? Steps updated on the main post.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert ya ineresting thought. Also was thinking if i can deliberately call the didReceiveMemoryWarning and then will the OS clean up everything?